# Cygwin Bash.exe vs. mintty.exe

Tags: windows, cygwin

I am trying to run Unix commands on both the `bash.exe` and `mintty.exe`, found in `Cygwin64/bin` (e.g., usr/bin/bash.exe). When I try to run the Unix commmand `ls`, I get `bash: ls: command not found`. However, when I click on the desktop icon for the Cygwin terminal, and enter `ls` into the resulting Cygwin terminal, the Unix commmands like `ls` work! Why do Unix commands not work on `bash.exe` and `mintty.exe`, but on the terminal the results from clicking the icon? Furthermore, what is the difference the two shells brought by `bash.exe` and `mintty.exe`?

Comment: Please specify how you run the command "in mintty".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

These two programs are not in any way alternatives to one another. Bash is a [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), and MinTTY is a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). MinTTY normally runs your user's shell within itself, which may or may not be Bash. You normally use the two programs together.

If you examine the MinTTY shortcut that Cygwin's `setup.exe` builds, you will find that it isn't a simple launch of the program. It runs it as `mintty -`, which tells MinTTY to run your user's shell as a "login" shell.

This is the problem you have run into. If you run `bash.exe` without options, you just get the naked shell, with its default configuration, which means it doesn't do things like add the Cygwin `/bin` to your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Likewise, if you run `mintty.exe` without options, it runs your user's shell without options. When you give a dash to `mintty.exe` instead of a program name, it runs your user's shell as a login shell: `bash -l`, rather than just `bash`. That option causes Bash to read in a bunch of startup scripts immediately after launch, which sets up the command PATH and a lot more besides.

Thus, if you had to run `bash.exe` outside MinTTY for some reason, you could say `bash -l` to get behavior somewhat closer to that of `bash.exe` when run via `mintty -`. You would lose out on all of the terminal emulator features, however. MinTTY has much better copy-paste behavior than Windows' console does, for example, particularly on Windows 8 and older.

(The initial release of Windows 10 included [a much-improved console](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/), and the more recent [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) add-on improves things further, but MinTTY remains the more powerful option, IMHO, particularly when working with Cygwin.)

Say `man mintty` at a Cygwin command prompt for a fuller explanation of all the things MinTTY does for you. This particular question was answered in the **INVOCATION** section of [the MinTTY manual page](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html).

Comment: @WarrenYoung : Basically correct, but you can ask mintty to run any program you like, in this respect, you could say that you run a program in mintty. Of course this makes only sense, if it is a program which interacts with a tty - for instance `irb` or an interactive Python session.