# Basic cygwin commands from python subprocess

Tags: python, windows, bash, shell

I want to run cygwin from python and execute cygwin commands.

I am using Windows, so I want to run commands in cygwin not cmd. I am using Python 3.6.1.

I just want to know how to run basic commands so I can work from there like `ls`. I have tried:

- `subprocess.call("E:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe", "ls")` (something like this, but it does not work)
- the solution below suggested by @pstatix, which uses Popen(). Running stdin.close() after stdin.write(b'ls') results in a `/usr/bin/bash: line 1: ls: command not found` error

I am able to do the following:

- open cygwin: `subprocess.call("E:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe")`
- (run commmands on Windows cmd: `subprocess.call("dir", shell=True)`)

Is this possible in this format? 
Does cygwin automatically close when I run the next python command, or do I need to exit before that?

I am relatively new to this.

Comment: You still havent showed your full set of code lines. Update your post to show a series of lines similar to my answer. We need to see it all in order to help.

Comment: Your code and the above lines is literally all I have. I am trying to figure out how this work so I can build upon it and run/write other commands, I really have nothing else beside that at the moment.

Comment: You should be able to run a lot of commands directly without having to run bash and write to its stdin. The Unix command line mostly consists of little programs like `/bin/ls`, which for you is probably `E:/cygwin/bin/ls.exe`.

Comment: @sandboxj Just as eryksun has commented, `bash.exe` opens up an empty shell without any options (such as /bash/bin); [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031164/cygwin-bash-exe-vs-mintty-exe#) is an SO post discussing mintty.exe vs bash.exe explaining just that. Short of that, my request for you to add code was to add it in full such like my posted answer. You are simply posting bullet points with some reference to what you have tried. Show us the full code, indents and all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen("E:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("ls")
p.stdin.close()
out = p.stdout.read()
print (out)
```

Comment: `p.stdin.write("ls")` throws an error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required not 'str'". Seems like "ls" is not a proper argument for .write() or am I doing something wrong? Other commands seem to work.

Comment: @sandboxj What version of Python on you on? To send a bytes-like, simply do `p.stdin.write(b'ls')`. However, there is no problem with the code as is on Python 2.7.13

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.1. The proposed solution with (b'ls') makes the .write line work, but when entering `p.std.in.close()` it oddly returns `/usr/bin/bash: line 1: ls: command not found`. Also, when entering the remaining two lines, it ultimately prints `b''`

Comment: @sandboxj Why are you writing `p.std.in.close()`? There is no `.` in the middile of `stdin`. You should update your posted question with the full code you are testing in question; we can go from there.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo here in stackoverflow. In the python shell, I have every line as you have typed above. Not sure what I should add to the question, but will edit and refer to your posted code.

Comment: By default Popen() in Pythin 3 communicates using bytes. To open its stdin/stdout/stderr in text mode and communicate using str pass `encoding`, `error` or `universal_newlines=True`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Comment: With @phd 's addition, I can pass in 'ls' into `.write` without the `b`, but `.close()` still throws the same error as mentioned above. Also, where is that path `/usr/bin/bash` coming from. This is not mentioned in any of the commands.

Comment: I have just searched for that error and it might be a pathing PATHing issue (...?), but I have definitely set the environment variables. Do I need to move them up before certain other variable?

Comment: This code works once I ran Python using administrator rights.

Comment: I had the `/usr/bin/bash: line 1: ls: command not found` error. I fixed this by giving the full path: `/bin/ls`, which worked

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['E:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe', '-c', '. /etc/profile; ls'], 
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(p.communicate()[0]))
```

This will open bash, execute the commands provided after `-c` and exit.

You need the prepended `. /etc/profile;` because bash is beeing started in a non-interactive mode, thus none of the environment variables are intialized and you need to source them yourself.

If you have cygwin installed over the **babun** software in your **user folder** (like I have) the code looks like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from os.path import expandvars

p = Popen([expandvars('%userprofile%/.babun/cygwin/bin/bash.exe'), '-c', '. /etc/profile; ls'], 
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(p.communicate()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the sollution mentioned above were giving issues like :
p.stdin.write("ls")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I fixed it with command sent in byte format

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    p = Popen(r"C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    p.stdin.write(b"ls")
    p.stdin.close()
    out = p.stdout.read()
    print(out)
```